How to Highlight Active Buttons Based on Scroll Position in Wordpress elementor
How do Highlight Active Buttons Based on Scroll Position in Wordpress Elementor?
I cannot change the color of the button when it's getting active. and when I am clicking on the button it goes slightly up then it comes back why?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
